# Can anyone explain why anyone needs angle brackets when they can use colon, which is much more readable?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Using Angle brackets example:

`Table.jsx`

```js
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';

export interface Props {
  filtered: string[][]
};

const Table: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ filtered }) => {
  return (
    <table />
  )
};

export default Table;
```

Using props example:

`Table.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';

export interface Props {
  filtered: string[][]
};

const Table = ({ filtered }: Props) => {
  return (
    <table />
  )
};

export default Table;
```

Why use angle brackets when colon does the job? What is the real benefit of using angle brackets, and why would I choose it over just using colon?

Thanks

Comment: You are mixing generic type with "regular" type.

Comment: Your first example gives type to both `Table` and it's arguments. The second example does not care about the type of `Table` which can be a real problem if you want to use it in a context where only a component is possible.

Comment: @sulthan thanks for reply. So using <Props> like I have in my example - does that mean Table return value should be in the format of Props?

Comment: The first defines a component with the given props. The second defines a random function which takes the given object as an argument.  Once you attempt to use it in a place that expects a component (using a type), then your second example won't work.

Comment: @Sultan. So is there an example you could point me to that would make the angular bracket function work where the random function not work to help explain your statement?

Comment: You should check this out :) https://github.com/piotrwitek/react-redux-typescript-guide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Edit: "Why use a generic type?"

### A)

One reason is to be able to use the provided type in multiple ways. For example, in the official type definition from React:

```
interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
    (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, any> | null;
    propTypes?: WeakValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: Partial<P>;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

Because it is defined using a generic, the `FunctionComponent` interface "knows" the following things about implementations of the interface:

1. The type of the first function argument
2. The type of the `propTypes` static property
3. The type of the `defaultProps` static property

### B)

Another reason is that the alternative gets messy fairly quickly. Take the following as a simplified version of the `FunctionComponent` interface, implemented without generics:

```
import React from 'react';

export interface FunctionComponentProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export interface FunctionComponent {
    (props: FunctionComponentProps, context?: any): React.ReactElement<any, any> | null;
}
```

We'd run into problems when we want to use that type:

```
export interface MyComponentProps extends FunctionComponentProps {
  children: boolean; // invalid - can't change interface prop type
  className: string;
}

export interface MyComponent extends FunctionComponent {
  // invalid - same problem, cannot redeclare function signature
  (props: MyComponentProps, context?: any): React.ReactElement<any, any> | null;
}

// inferred types of children and classNames is any because of the re-declarations
export const Button: MyComponent = ({ children, className }) => {
  return <button className={className}>{children ? 'YES' : 'NO'}</button>;
};
```

It "works" if your custom types do not extend the provided type, but you'll end up with an awful lot of useless boilerplate code if you re-invent the wheel for every component.

```
export interface MyComponentProps {
  children: boolean;
  className: string;
}

export interface MyComponent {
  (props: MyComponentProps, context?: any): React.ReactElement<any, any> | null;
}

export const Button: MyComponent = ({ children, className }) => {
  return <button className={className}>{children ? 'YES' : 'NO'}</button>;
};
```

## Original Answer

The angle bracket syntax provides more information to the type checking system, so the benefits come in the form of better type checking.

For example:

**Table.tsx**

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";

export interface Props {
  filtered: string[][];
}

const Table: FunctionComponent<Props> = ({ filtered }) => {
  console.log("filtered = ", filtered);
  // Type check fails because a ReactNode is not returned
  //return <table />;
};

Table.defaultProps = {
  // Type check fails because null is not a valid value for filtered
  filtered: null
};

export default Table;
```

**Table_bad.tsx**

```
import React from "react";

export interface Props {
  filtered: string[][];
}

const Table = ({ filtered }: Props) => {
  console.log("filtered = ", filtered);
  // Typescript does not know enough to complain that the render function does not return a ReactNode
  //return <table />;
};

Table.defaultProps = {
  // Typescript does not know that defaultProps should implement Props
  filtered: null
};

export default Table;
```

**Demo**

https://codesandbox.io/s/so-61508203-56xum?file=/src/components/Table_bad.tsx

Comment: Thank you for this response. Other than giving better type information in editor, it doesn't explain why that is? What exactly does FunctionComponent provide that colon doesn't?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. It better explains the benefit. 1) Using a generic type is to restrict then, any further extension of what would otherwise be done via extending types. 2) It is specific to a function, not for just any other primitive type.  3) The benefit of 1 and 2 then make the advantage of a single location for the type checking system of more value because developers then know there is only one place this is defined.

Comment: The only contest of your argument in terms of being 'messy' is that angular brackets themselves are by their very nature already messy visually. Using colon within javascript is already a bad symbol choice when that same symbol has been used for over 20 years in javascript object notation. Adding angular brackets is compounding this messiness, by competing with visual cue of htrml tags. The question of productivity over strict code adherence will determine the economic impact typescript will have on a popular language - react, where angular 2 lost trend. Different symbols could have been used.

Answer (score 1):

I now understand the use case for angle brackets regarding generic types, but I still question why we add this extra level of complexity.

## Understanding a Generic Type

1. How to declare generic type

```js
type MyGenericType<T> = T & { 
  name: string,
  somethingOptional?: number
};
```

2. and 3. How to invoke a generic type by passing it a 'generic' type of your choosing and assigning it to variable type (THE USE CASE FOR USING ANGULAR BRACKETS)

```js
interface Person {
  age: number;
}

let person1: MyGenericType<Person>;
```

4. An example of supplying the correct properties now to that type?

```js
person1 = {
  name: 'Johnson',
  somethingOptional: 21,
  age: 41,
};
```

## But why use a generic type? Why not just extend the type like this?

1. How to invoke an interface

```js
interface insteadofGenericType {
  name: string,
  somethingOptional?: number
}
```

2. How to extend and interface with another interface

```js
interface Person extends insteadofGenericType {
  age: number;
}
```

3. How to assign type to variable

```js
let person2: Person;
```

4. Example of variable properties

```js
person2 = {
  name: 'Johnson',
  somethingOptional: 21,
  age: 41,
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this doesn't completely answer my own question but gets closer to it. I still want to understand why angle bracket is used over colon. Still, with regard to React - 'FunctionComponent' specifically, provides a benefit in that in provides type for children.

Example link: 
- https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/children/

```js
import React, {FunctionComponent} from 'react';

export const Tr:FunctionComponent = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      {children}
    </tr>
  )
};
```

Comment: This seems nicely described here - (ie the makeup of a FunctionComponent - previously named StatelessFunctionComponent): https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html

Comment: Within the above link, it goes on to describe using 'as' instead of angle brackets because angle brackets were not previously allowed in .tsx files: "The as operator is available in both .ts and .tsx files, and is identical in behavior to the angle-bracket type assertion style."

Comment: Unrelated to angle brackets per se, but an interesting way to add custom html tags to react and pass its internal validation, if wanting to write more pure html5 solutions: 
"declare namespace JSX {interface IntrinsicElements {foo: any;}}
<foo />; // ok
<bar />; // error
"